# Getting "ORA-01435: user does not exist" error when trying to change admin password in oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I installed oracle XE 18c and Apex 18.2 using this guide: https://www.aflorestorres.com/2019/03/install-oracle-database-18c-express-and.html. When I try to login into my apex I get "Invalid login Credentials" ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkQ01.png)). 
So I try to change admin password using '@apxchpwd.sql' and I get this :

> SQL> @apxchpwd.sql
>   ...set_appun.sql
>   ERROR:
>   ORA-01435: user does not exist.

Comment: Did you connect as SYS when you ran apxchpwd.sql? If not, do so.

Comment: Also, make sure you're connecting to the correct CDB or PDB.